# SQL Server 2012 Update table rate based on rate in table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update, outer-join

I have two tables and below is the example

```
Table1
KEY     BEGIN_DATE         TOTAL_RATE    
1       1974-01-01        3    
1       1981-01-01        3    
1       1983-01-01        4    
1       1985-07-01        4        
1       1989-10-01        7    
1       1990-07-01        10    
1       1997-10-01        11    
1       2008-04-01        13
```

TABLE2

```
KEY     END_DATE          RATE_REDUCED    
1       1989-09-30       2    
1       1997-09-31       4
```

From Table 2 if key matches then we need to reduce TOTALRATE from Table 1
with RATEREDUCED in Table 2 where BEGINDATE > ENDDATE and it should happen
till the end of table 2 ENDDATE

EXPECTED RESULTS/UPDATE TO TABLE 1:
RESULT

```
KEY     BEGIN_DATE        NEW_RATE    
1       1974-01-01       3    
1       1981-01-01       3    
1       1983-01-01       4    
1       1985-07-01       4    
1       1989-10-01       7  - 2      = 5 (Date is Greater than 1989-09-30)     
1       1990-07-01       10 - 2      = 8 (Date is Greater than 1989-09-30)    
1       1997-10-01       11 - 2 - 4  = 5 (Date is Greater than two dates)    
1       2008-04-01       13 - 2 - 4  = 7 (Date is Greater than two dates)
```

I have many keys in table two and table one.
Is update with join possible

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the difference in performance between using a join or using a subquery. Maybe you can try out the solutions mentioned in the other answers and compare it to a (simpler?) subquery approach:

```
update table1
set total_rate = total_rate - 
    (select COALESCE(sum(new_rate),0)
     from table2
     where begin_date > end_date
       and table1.key = table2.key)
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan, this works and i don't see any difference in performance

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a good application of `outer apply`:

```
select t1.*,
       (t1.total_rate - coalesce(t2.rate_reduced, 0)) as total_rate
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select sum(t2.rate_reduced) as rate_reduced
      from table2 t2
      where t1.begin_date > t2.end_date and
            t1.key = t2.key
     ) t2;
```

EDIT:

If you want to turn this into an `update`, that is easy:

```
update t1 
    set total_rate = (t1.total_rate - coalesce(t2.rate_reduced, 0)) 
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select sum(t2.rate_reduced) as rate_reduced
      from table2 t2
      where t1.begin_date > t2.end_date and
            t1.key = t2.key
     ) t2;
```

Comment: @StephanLechner . . . I focused more on the "EXPECTED RESULTS" than the "UPDATE" part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Gordon's, here we use use an Update in a CROSS APPLY.  This approach will only update the records which match the criteria

```
Update Table1 Set TOTAL_RATE=TOTAL_Rate-B.Adj
 From  Table1 A
 Cross Apply (
              Select Adj=sum(RATE_REDUCED) 
               From  Table2 
               Where END_DATE<=A.BEGIN_DATE and [Key]=A.[Key] 
              ) B
 Where B.Adj is not NULL
```

**The Updated Table1 Looks like this now**

```
KEY BEGIN_DATE  TOTAL_RATE
1   1974-01-01  3
1   1981-01-01  3
1   1983-01-01  4
1   1985-07-01  4
1   1989-10-01  5
1   1990-07-01  8
1   1997-10-01  5
1   2008-04-01  7
```